# How to pass button object to function

Tags: c#

I have several buttons to click, and all the same function (that I want to create), they just differ by controller's name. For example:

```csharp
private void markX()
        {
            buttonName.Text = "X";
            buttonName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
```

How can I pass the button object that that is modified in the function into the function's parameters?

Comment: How is `markX` called? You could just do `markX(Button button)`.

Comment: Make it a `Click` event handler, attach it to each button, and use the `sender` parameter as the button to change.

Comment: Andu, please don't forget to let the answerers know whether their answer was helpful. Accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a `Click` event handler, attach it to each button, and use the `sender` parameter as the button to change.

```
void button_Click(Object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if(button != null)
    {
        button.Text = "X";
        button.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass the name of the button, you just need to pass an object of type button as an argument to your method.

```
private void markX(Button b)
{
    b.Text = "Text";
    b.Foreground = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: This is my recommendation based on the assumption that you want to do more with your button than just modify it when clicked (avoiding eating up your click event just to perform the modifications).

Answer (score 0):

Use "sender":

```
private void Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((Button)sender).Text = "X";
}
```

sender holds instance of event caller.

Answer (score -1):

The click handler for the button click event has the following objects.

```
      Object sender
      EventArgs e
```

This will give you the name of the Button that was clicked, and just pass that to your function.

```
      ((Button)sender).Tag
```

Here is some sample code

```
      private void Button_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

       string name = ((Button)sender).Tag;

       markX(name);
      }
```