# How to pass a button array into a function

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I'm trying to create a function that will send a serial string to a com port and change colors every time a button is pressed.

I have figured out how to do this with one button, but now I want to make an array of 140 buttons that can all be passed through this function.

My problem is that all 140 buttons perform the function of the first button, not what their individual function should be, which is send a different serial command and turn blue when it is on.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool[] buttonStatus = new bool[140];
    Button[] buttonArray = new Button[140];

    private SerialPort LB;//"LB for left bottom module

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initializing();
        CreatingNewButtons();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes Serial ports to be used
    /// </summary>
    private void Initializing()
    {
        try
        {
            LB = new SerialPort();
            LB.BaudRate = 57600;
            LB.PortName = "COM9";
            LB.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error connecting");
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates all 140 buttons at startup
    /// </summary>
    private void CreatingNewButtons()
    {
        int horizotal = 80;
        int vertical = 30;

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonArray.Length; i++)
        {
            buttonArray[i] = new Button();
            buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(25, 25);
            buttonArray[i].Location = new Point(horizotal, vertical);
            if ((i == 10) || (i == 20) || (i == 30) || (i == 40) || (i == 50) ||
                (i == 60) || (i == 70) || (i == 80) || (i == 90) || (i == 100) || 
                (i == 110) || (i == 120) || (i == 130))
            {
                vertical = 30;
                horizotal = horizotal + 30;
            }
            else
                vertical = vertical + 30;
            this.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);
            // Add a Button Click Event handler
            buttonArray[i].Click += new EventHandler(buttonArray_Click);
        }
    }

    void sendStringToAllModules (string stringToSend)
    {
        LB.WriteLine(stringToSend);//write string text to arduino
    }

    private void sendStringBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LB.WriteLine(stringTextBox.Text);//write string text to arduino
    }

    private void receiveStringBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        receiveStringTextBox.Text = LB.ReadExisting();
    }

    #region pushbuttonCode

    /// <summary>
    /// send function index and sends either on or off to leds of modules
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void toggleLEDs(int i)
    {

        if (!buttonStatus[i])
        {
            sendStringToAllModules("1;" + i + ";");
            buttonArray[i].BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
            buttonStatus[i] = !buttonStatus[i];
        }
        else
        {
            sendStringToAllModules("2;" + i + ";"); 
            buttonArray[i].BackColor = Color.Gainsboro; 
            buttonStatus[i] = !buttonStatus[i]; 
        } 
    } 

    private void buttonArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this button works
    {
        toggleLEDs(0);
    }
    private void buttonArray1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this one doesn't
    { 
        toggleLEDs(0); 
    } 
    #endregion 
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it intentional that both of your buttonArray_Clickx methods pass the exact same value (0) to the parameter?

Comment: you can use the answer on this post to get you started..pretty straight forward http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893512/how-to-pass-button-object-to-function

Answer (score 0):

The sender parameter will be the actual button that was pressed. Find the index of it in buttonArray and send the index to toggleLEDs as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is to create your own button type by deriving it from `System.Windows.Forms.Button`

```
public class CommandButton : Button
{
    public Action<CommandButton> Execute { get; set; }

    public CommandButton (Action<CommandButton> action)
    {
        Execute = action;
    }
}
```

Now you can create a button by passing it the desired action as lambda expression:

```
var button = new CommandButton(btn => { 
    MessageBox.Show("I am button " + btn.Name);
    toggleLEDs(0);
    btn.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
});
```

You can also just pass it a method name of a method having the right signature:

```
void MyMethod(CommandButton button)
{
    DoSomething();
}

...

var button = new CommandButton(MyMethod);
```

Then you can execute the action like this:

```
private void buttonArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (CommandButton)sender;
    button.Execute(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Windows.Forms.Label.Tag property to identify each button.  Add the following line to your button creation loop:

```
buttonArray[i].Tag = i;
```

Then, code a single event handler.  Inside the handler, you can access the Tag of whichever button click caused the handler to fire, and pass that value to your function.

```
private void buttonArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toggleLEDs((Button)sender.Tag);
}
```